# Java Regular Expression to Remove tags from html

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

```
<table><tr><td>HEADER</td><td>Header Value <supporting value></td></tr><tr><td>SUB</td><td>sub value. write to <test@gmail.com></td></tr><tr><td>START DATE</td><td>11/23/ 2016</td></tr><tr><td>END DATE</td><td>11/23/2016</td></tr></table>
```

The above text is my html String, need to extract values for HEADER, SUB,START DATE and END DATE. I used Jsoup to extract the values but I have issues with non-html element tags. The API either skips these elements OR adds an ending tag which was not there in the first place.

So my idea is to replace non-html element tags with `&lt;` and then use Jsooup to extract the values

Any suggestions??

Comment: Tradition must be respected: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1225328

Comment: You're asking for a solution, but you haven't defined the problem well. What pattern are you looking for?

Comment: @sp00m You can't use regex to parse an entire html document, but in this case, only extracting some values that follow a well-defined pattern, _is_ possible.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's not quite the same. These aren't valid HTML tags.

Comment: Not a good idea.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg .

Comment: The problem: Need to extract values for HEADER, SUB, START DATE and END DATE. But while extracting it using using an API, non-html elements are skipped. So all I want to do is to find the non-html element tags and replace them with &lt; &gt;

Comment: @Srini Please update the question with the details, do not add them as comments. Right now, it does sound like a dupe or off-topic question. Add your own attempts at solving the issue, that could also help others help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to refer [jSoup](https://jsoup.org/) to parse HTML documents. You can extract and manipulates data using this api.

Comment: It's not valid HTML.

Comment: @shmosel please elaborate

Comment: `<supporting value>` is an invalid HTML tag. Same for the other.

Comment: @shmosel Worked for me while doing POC.

Comment: I did use Jsoup, when I parse the html string using Jsoup, ending tags </supporting value> and </test@gmail.com> are automatically added. So my plan is to find a pattern and replace "<>" for non-html elements. After which I'll parse using Jsoup.

Comment: This is what you are looking for if I am not wrong. replaceAll("\\<.*?>","")

Comment: This expression removed rest of the <table> <tr> <td> tags. I need these tags to extract HEADER, SUB, START DATE and END DATE values as a Key-Value pair

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the content using this regex:

```
/<td>[^<]*<([^>]*)><\/td>/
```

assumed the markup layout always looks the same.

Although you can't parse a complete HTML document using a regular expression, because it is not a context-free language, a partial extraction like this in fact *is* possible.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, got all the tags from the html String using the pattern <([^\s>/]+)

Then replaced all the tags except for TR and TD with  "&lt" "&gt". When I parse the text using Jsoup I get the desired value.

Please find the code below,

```
public class JsoupParser2 {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    String orginalString, replaceString = null;
    HashSet<String> tagSet = new HashSet<String>();
    HashMap<String,String> notes = new HashMap<String,String>();

    Document document = null;
    try{

        //Read the html content as String
        File testFile = new File("C:\\test.html");
        List<String> content = Files.readLines(testFile,  Charsets.UTF_8);
        String testContent = content.get(0);

        //Get all the tags present in the html content
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<([^\\s>/]+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(testContent);
        while(m.find()) {
            String tag = m.group(1);
            tagSet.add(tag);
        }

        //Replace the tags thats non-html
        for(String replaceTag : tagSet){
            if(!"table".equals(replaceTag) && !"tr".equals(replaceTag) && !"td".equals(replaceTag)){
                orginalString = "<"+replaceTag+">";
                replaceString = "&lt;"+replaceTag+"&gt;";
                testContent = testContent.replaceAll(orginalString, replaceString);
            }
        }

        //Parse the html content
        document = Jsoup.parse(testContent, "", Parser.xmlParser());

        //traverse through TR and TD to get to the values
        //store the values in the map
        Elements pTags = document.select("tr");
        for (Element tag : pTags) {
            if(!tag.getElementsByTag("td").isEmpty()){
                String key = tag.getElementsByTag("td").get(0).text().trim();
                String value = tag.getElementsByTag("td").get(1).html().trim();
                System.out.println("KEY : "+key); System.out.println("VALUE : "+value);
                notes.put(key, value);
                System.out.println("==============================================");
            }
        } 

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ioobe){
        System.out.println("ioobe");
    }
}
```

}